# JQuery (should not to) hides form after Submitting it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, submit

I have the tiny homepage, which works in the same window by hiding/showing necessary blocks via display block/none properties using JQuery script which is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show").click(function (){
    $(".web, .about, .tel, .email").hide();
    $("." + $(this).attr("show-class")).fadeIn("fast");
  });
});
```

HTML is:

```
<li><a href="#" class="show" show-class="email">E-mail</a></li>

<div class="email">

  <form method="post" action="">                    
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name (required)">                     
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail (required)">                     
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>                        
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">                    
  </form>

  <?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $to = 'example@example.com'; 
  $subject = 'Hi! From Example.com';

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

  if ($_POST['submit']) {
  if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) { 
  echo '<p>Your message has been sent.</p>';
  } else { 
  echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again.</p>'; 
  }
  } else {
  echo '<p>Please fill in required information.</p>';
  }
  }
  ?>

</div>
```

And the problem is after successfully or not, submitting the form (pressing the submit button) the block with form hides and only after pressing "E-mail" link again one of the messages (like "Your message has been sent.") appears below/along with the form.

So how could I stop the form from disappearing after submitting it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$(".web, .about, .tel, .email").hide();`
That's what's hiding your inputs.

Adjustment to your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $("." + $(this).attr("show-class")).fadeIn("fast");
  });
});`
```

Comment: Thank you, however the thing is than each new appearing block should hide previous one, since they're placed in the same position. So by using your method each block appears below previous block. And the form still disappears after pressing submit button.